# Detect any USB device activity using C#

Tags: c#

How to detect usb activity using C#? I want to use it to trigger a function. In my case the device was detected as **USB composite device**.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately there is no info about the manufacture

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by writing "usb activity". Technically speaking, there is always USB activity between a connected USB device and the USB host. USB is a protocol that is making heavy use of polling, with the USB host continuously polling connected USB devices with a frequency between 125 Hz and 1000 Hz. In other words, there would be no need attempting to detect USB activity because there is always USB activity between the USB host (computer) and connected USB devices.

Comment: Specifically, I want to detect a proximity card encoder device. I need to run a function when a card is detected.